# Allow duplicates in SlugRelatedField many-to-many relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `SlugRelatedField` set up as so:

```
items = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    slug_field='name', many=True, queryset=Item.objects.all())
```

Currently, I am sending a request to the database in the following form:

```
{
    items: [
        "item1",
        "item1",
        "item2",
    ]
}
```

However, if I query the same object then I get the following:

```
{
    items: [
        "item1",
        "item2",
    ]
}
```

How do I make it so that DRF will insert exactly what I send it and not remove duplicates.

Comment: What about this, https://drf-multislugfield.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html

Comment: @JPG I don't think that has anything for many-to-many with duplicates.

Comment: it is not troble of drf it is a rule of django Many2May https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by making three changes. All code below has been changed to avoid copyright problems with my company, so sorry if I made a typo. First, I made a custom many-to-many model that allows for duplicate entries:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(
        Foo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(
        Bar, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Then I added a `through` argument to my Foo class's ManyToMany field to use the new model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Foo, through='FooBar')
```

However, just doing this causes an `AttributeError: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use my_package.FooBar's Manager instead.` This is because custom many-to-many models can't be automatically created by Django Rest Framework. So we need to implement a couple of custom serializer methods to get around that:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    instance = Foo()
    instance.x = validated_data['x']
    instance.y = validated_data['y']
    instance.save()
    for bar in validated_data['bars']:
        relation = FooBar(foo=instance, bar=bar)
        relation.save()
    return instance

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.table = validated_data.get('x', instance.x)
    instance.status = validated_data.get('y', instance.y)
    instance.save()
    if 'bars' in validated_data:
        FooBar.objects.filter(foo=instance).delete()
        for bar in validated_data.get('bars', []):
            relation = FooBar(foo=instance, bar=bar)
            relation.save()
    return instance
```